# Selenium XPath multiple selection

Tags: selenium, xpath

I want to find all elements in the table that match the following conditions:

```
-div text contains '2019';

-div class='excellent';
```

here is the HTML code excerpt:

```
<tr>
    <td>Name of Person1</td>
        <td>
        <div class="testDate">21/12/2019</div>
        <div class="excellent"></div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
     <td>Name of Person2</td>
         <td>
         <div class="testDate">01/12/2017</div>
     </td>
</tr>
```

I tried this solution:

```
//tr/td[2][div/text()='21/12/2019'][div[@class='starred']]
```

but I need the year only and not entirely date.

Comment: Hi Gregory,

See this xpath example for containing text, rather than equaling text.
https://www.guru99.com/using-contains-sbiling-ancestor-to-find-element-in-selenium.html#1

Comment: @Gregory, Please add your expected output.

Answer (score 2):

Use the below xpath.

```
//tr/td[div[contains(.,'2019')]and div[@class='excellent']]
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]